# Graphql: Difference between the 'input' type and the 'interface' type in graphQL

Tags: input, graphql, interface

My understanding of graphql is limited and I'm starting out going through the docs and I see that input types and interfaces (seem) to serve the same purpose to me. (but I don't know much about graphql and didn't find a difference in the docs)

so my question is:
what is the difference between an input type and an interface?

just expecting an explanation from someone with any level of expertise that wants to take a shot at the question.

Comment: Are you sure you mean `interface`s? https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#input-types writes "*In the GraphQL schema language, input types look exactly the same as regular object types, but with the keyword `input` instead of `type`*" - contrasting them with object types not interfaces. Which documentation are you reading?

Answer (score 0):

> "An interface specifies a set of fields that multiple object types can include"

An interface is used as a building block for `type` - it's not quite object-oriented in that while multiple types can reuse the same interface that can only go one layer deep.

`input type` is used to define the shape of an `input` to a query or mutation. It is particularly useful when a query or mutation requires more than just a simple list of scalar keys as input.